# Problemas con tipo de dato en array dentro de una clase

Tags: php, pdo

Estoy utilizado `PHP/PDO` con `DAO` y `VO`.

Este es el index.php:

```
<?php
    require ('includes/config.php');
    $DAO = new TrabajoDAO();
    $listas = $DAO->Listar();
    $tpl = new Plantilla();
    $tpl->assign('lista', $listas);
    $tpl->display("crud.tpl.php");
?>
```

Este es el archivo TrabajoVO.class.php

```
<?php
    class TrabajoVO {
        private $codigo;
        private $nombre;

        public function TrabajoVO($codigo, $nombre) {
            $this->codigo = $codigo;
            $this->nombre = $nombre;
        }
    }
?>
```

Este es el archivo TrabajoDAO.class.php

```
<?php
    class TrabajoDAO {

        public function __construct(){
        }

    public function Listar()
    {
        try
        {
            $BD = new ConexionDB();
            $stm = $BD->prepare("SELECT codigo, nombre FROM tabla");
            $stm->execute();
            foreach($stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $fila)
            {
                $resultado[] = new TrabajoVO($fila['codigo'], $fila['nombre']);
            }
            return $resultado;
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

        public function __destruct(){
        }
    }
?>
```

Esta es la plantilla:

```
{section name=i loop=$lista}
<tr class="success">
    <td class="text-center">{counter}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{$lista[i]->codigo}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{$lista[i]->stud}</td>
</tr>
{/section}
```

Al ejecutarlo me aparece este mensaje:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

en la línea del `$resultado[]` de `TrabajoDAO`.

Comment: Te está diciendo que $fila es un objeto y no un array,  debes cojer el valor de código con **$fila->codigo**, no con $fila['codigo']. Lo mismo con nombre

Comment: Tú solo te estás poniendo el pie, al hacer `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` estás regresando un objeto, en ves del arreglo que normalmente regresa PDO, puedes una de dos: hacer lo de este comentario de arriba o quitar el `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`

Answer (score -1):

Debes declarar el array $resultado antes de su utilización en el bucle:

```
<?php
    class TrabajoDAO {

        public function __construct(){
        }

    public function Listar()
    {
        try
        {
            $resultado = array();
            $BD = new ConexionDB();
            $stm = $BD->prepare("SELECT codigo, nombre FROM tabla");
            $stm->execute();
            foreach($stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $fila)
            {
                $resultado[] = new TrabajoVO($fila['codigo'], $fila['nombre']);
            }
            return $resultado;
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

        public function __destruct(){
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: También lo probé, y aparece el mismo mensaje.

Comment: @Piropeator. Ok. Prueba con lo que te dicen los comentarios más arriba. De todos modos deberías declarar el array antes de comenzar a guardar valores.